# Should I drop book of proof for a discrete maths book?

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, book-recommendation

My aim is to attein a good level of proof writing so I started studying book of proof and I was planning on going through a discrete maths book after that, but then realized that they have a lot of overlap in terms of content and I want to know if it's worthwhile to continue studying book of proof of if I should skip it.

Comment: Its purely my opinion: But you can Go through the Discrete maths book first, and while going through each chapter, you could just have a glance at all the things in Book of proof and check if you have anything you missed. If you do not have that much time to go through both books, read the discrete maths book and completely drop the book of  proof.

Comment: Using a "book of proofs" has no more interest for becoming good at mathematics than using a "book of style" for somebody who wants to be proficient in litterature...